# How to find the Firefox Profile Path using webdriver

Tags: firefox, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to find the path of the Firefox Profile path , I am using the following code for

```
static String HubHost;

static String HubPort;
HubHost=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName().toString().trim();

HubPort = "4444";

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

System.out.println("Profile name:"+profile.layoutOnDisk().);

URL grid_url=new URL("http://"+HubHost+":"+HubPort+"/wd/hub");

webdriver = new CustomRemoteWebDriver(grid_url,dc);

String suggestedProfile = System.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");

System.out.println("Profile name:"+ suggestedProfile);
```

A new profile is generating in the TEMP folder with the name like "`anonymous651976431316177878webdriver-profile`" but unable to get this name through code .

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to know the *temporary* path of the new profile, as it  will be removed after the WebDriver session has completed?

Comment: I want to change the data in CERT8.db file which will deal with browser SSL certificates and cookies

Comment: What are you attempting to deal with in regards to SSL certs and cookies? WebDriver already has a lot of these types of scenerios integrated in the Profile configuration of the browser before you initialize the browser. I'd recommend checking into that first: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#SSL_Certificates

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to get system property "webdriver.firefox.profile" you somehow should set it.
Could you provide the output of:

```
System.out.println("Profile name:"+ suggestedProfile);
```

If you haven't set that system property, is should print:

```
Profile name:null
```

Comment: Hi,

when i print the 

System.out.println("Profile name:"+ suggestedProfile);
One new  folder is creating in the TEMP dir and printing in d console with name like "anonymous651976431316177878webdriver-profile".
In my case i need to access the profile path with out setting 
system property "webdriver.firefox.profile" as such
I need to create a default profile with out setting the profile path and need to access that profile path.
Thank You